# Pass Eloquent\Builder as parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Probably it's an easy answer, but I don't find it!
I'm using Eloquent to perform my queries into the database, having this code:

```
public function postSearch(Request $request)
{
    $query = Customer::select('identification', 'first_name', 'second_name', 'first_lastname', 'second_lastname', 'genre')
                ->where('identification', 'LIKE', "%$request->identification%")
                ->where('first_name', 'LIKE', "%$request->first_name%")
                ->Where('second_name', 'LIKE', "%$request->second_name%")
                ->Where('first_lastname', 'LIKE', "%$request->first_lastname%")
                ->Where('second_lastname', 'LIKE', "%$request->second_lastname%")
                ->Where('genre', 'LIKE', "%$request->genre%");
    $request->session()->put('list', $query->get());
    $customers = $query->paginate(20);
    return view('customer.index', compact('customers'));
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $query = Customer::select('identification', 'first_name', 'second_name', 'first_lastname', 'second_lastname', 'genre');
    $request->session()->put('list', $query->get());
    $customers = $query->paginate(20);
    return view('customer.index', compact('customers'));
}
```

It works perfectly, but now, I want to optimize it creating another funtion which receives the $query. Something like this:

```
public function displayResult(Builder $query,Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->put('list', $query->get());
        $customers = $query->paginate(20);
        return view('customer.index', compact('customers'));
    }
```

The objective is to call the function from my previous methods, e.g:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $query = Customer::select('identification', 'first_name', 'second_name', 'first_lastname', 'second_lastname', 'genre');
        $this->displayResult($query, $request);
    }
```

But, my view is not displaying nothing. Am I doing something wrong? 
Should I use a Model instead Builder parameter? If I do so, then it's displaying this error:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController::displayResult() must be an
>   instance of App\Http\Controllers\Model, instance of
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder given, called in ....on line 54 and defined

That line is exactly where I call to my new funtion.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is "public function displayResult(Builder $query,Request $request)" the current function signature that is causing the error? The error says that the function requires Model to be passed as first argument, yet here first argument is hinted as Builder - could you check your "use" statements? it seems like Builder is an alias for Model class.

Comment: No, the error is shown when I call the displayResult function, it means, from the index function. If I set the argument to Model then the error is shown. If I set to Builder, nothing is displayed, just a blank page. Even I'm using both classes in the use statement, Builder and Model.

Comment: I see. Well, Builder is the correct type for first argument of displayResult - I see no way why you'd want to change it to Model. I think I see the reason for blank page, posting the answer right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **displayResult()** method returns the view instance, but you forgot to return it from your controller's **index()** method.

Replace

```
$this->displayResult($query, $request);
```

with

```
return $this->displayResult($query, $request);
```